# Mail is not sending from server using C# asp.net web form

Tags: c#

Two days back mail was going but now mail is not going from my live site. Please check my below code any thing is wrong. Thank you in advance

Web.config code

```
  <appSettings>
<add key="SmtpClientclientPath" value="myvalues" />
<add key="gmailHost" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
<add key="SmtpClientclientPathPort" value="25" />
<add key="password" value="pas$W0rd" />-->
<add key="userName" value="info@mysite.in" />
<add key="password" value="test@1232" />
 </appSettings>
```

Below is my business logic code

```
 public void Insert_UserInformation(BusinessObject bo, out string Status)
{
    string statusmsg = string.Empty;
    dl.Insert_UserInformation(bo, out Status);
    if (Status == "Success")
    {
        try
        {
            string LinkPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["verifyuserpath"].ToString();
            LinkPath += "uhjkdfcxnawe781sewd=" + bo.Para20;
            string strBody;
            strBody = "";
            strBody = strBody + "Dear" + " " + bo.Para3 + "," + "<br><br>";
            strBody = strBody + "Thank you for your interest in the Testing Program. To verify your email id , please click the link below." + "<br><br>";
            strBody = strBody + "<a href=" + LinkPath + ">" + LinkPath + "</a><br><br>";
            strBody = strBody + "Your LogIn Id:" + " " + bo.Para4 + "" + "<br><br><br>";
            strBody = strBody + "With Regards" + "," + "<br>";
            strBody = strBody + "Testing Team";
            statusmsg = SendEmail(bo.Para8, "Testing Registration:Verification Mail", strBody);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Status = ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
}


public string SendEmail(string toAddress, string subject, string body)
 {
 string result = "Message Sent Successfully..!!";
 string senderID = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userName"].ToString();// use sender’s email id here..
  string senderPassword = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"].ToString(); // sender password here…
 try
 {
   SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
   {
     Host =System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["gmailHost"].ToString(), // smtp server address here…
     Port = int.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["gmailport"].ToString()),
     //Port = int.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpClientclientPathPort"].ToString()),
     EnableSsl = true,
     UseDefaultCredentials=false,
     Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(senderID, senderPassword),
     Timeout = 200000,
   };
   MailMessage message = new MailMessage(senderID, toAddress, subject, body);
   message.IsBodyHtml = true;
   smtp.Send(message);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     result = ex.Message.ToString();
 }
 return result;
  }
```

I checked my login details username and password also above credential working fine, why mail is not going from server, it is server problem what should have to check in web server. Thank you In Advance

Comment: `SmtpClient` and `Message` derive from `IDisposable` and should be disposed. Also you are catching exceptions to `statusmsg` and later you are not doing anything with it. You are hiding all exceptions from `SendEmail`

Comment: can you write your full answer. @FCin

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the full answer to your question. Please try this and let me know if the issue is fixed. As I pointed out, there might be exceptions coming from `SendEmail` that you are hiding.

Comment: But two days back mail was going on same code. @FCin

Comment: @user3754858 You never seem to do anything with `statusMsg`, so if you *do* have an error, you don't log it... You need to add full logging to your site as step #1...

Comment: @user3754858 That is why I am suspecting exceptions. Not disposing `SmtpClient` can pile up garbage, but I doubt that it would stop sending messages.

Comment: I login to above question credential. @RB.

Comment: Is there any chance of web server issue which have to check. @FCin@RB

Comment: Well, yes - there’s a chance of all sorts of things - but without logging you are going to be stabbing blindly in the dark to try and fix it!